# PLSQL new salary is not displaying or displaying wrong

Tags: stored-procedures, select, plsql, cursor

Thanks, for idea

> I have to write a procedure that computes number of project, and
>   average working hours of employees where employee id is passed as a
>   parameter to the procedure.  If the average working hours is less than
>   10 then employee’s salary remain the same, otherwise check if number
>   of project is less than 4 then 5% of salary, else 10% of salary is
>   added to the salary.
>
> something wrong with my output in plsql statement it is not displaying
>   new salary
>
> here is my plsql procedure:
>
> ```
> create or replace procedure view_data(p_id number) is
> cursor c1 
> is
>   select count(distinct a.projectid) as PRJ_COUNT, e.empid, e.empname, e.salary as old_sal, round(avg(a.hours),0)as AVG_HOURS
>   from assignment a join employee e
>   on a.empid=e.empid
>   where e.empid=p_id
>   group by e.empid,e.empname, e.salary;
> creader c1%rowtype;  
> cursor c2
> is
>   select empid, salary as new_sal
>   from employee 
>   where empid=p_id for update of salary;
> rate_rec c2%rowtype;
>
> v_new_salary number;
> begin
>   --open c1;
>   --fetch c1 into creader;
>   for creader in c1 loop
>
>   for rate_rec in c2 loop
>     if creader.avg_hours < 10 then
>       update employee set salary=rate_rec.new_sal
>       where empid=rate_rec.empid;
>
>     elsif creader.prj_count<4 then
>       update employee set salary=rate_rec.new_sal+rate_rec.new_sal*0.05
>       where empid=rate_rec.empid;
>
>     else
>       update employee set salary=rate_rec.new_sal+rate_rec.new_sal*0.1
>       where empid=rate_rec.empid;
>
>     end if;
>    select salary into v_new_salary from employee
>    where empid=creader.empid;
>
>   dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID: '||creader.empid);
>   dbms_output.put_line('Employee Name: '||creader.empname);
>   dbms_output.put_line('Number of projects: '||creader.prj_count);
>   dbms_output.put_line('Average Working Hours: '||creader.avg_hours);
>   dbms_output.put_line('Old Salary: '||rate_rec.new_sal);
>   dbms_output.put_line('New Salary: '||v_new_salary);
>
>   end loop;
>  end loop;
>
>
>
>   end view_data;
>   /
> ```
>
> here is the output:
>
> ```
> Employee ID: 101
> Employee Name: Marlen
> Number of projects: 3
> Average Working Hours: 87
> Old Salary: 39206
> New Salary: 41166
> ```

solution with using cursors:

```
create or replace procedure view_data(p_id number) is
cursor c1 
is
  select count(distinct a.projectid) as PRJ_COUNT, e.empid, e.empname, e.salary as old_sal, round(avg(a.hours),0)as AVG_HOURS
  from assignment a join employee e
  on a.empid=e.empid
  where e.empid=p_id
  group by e.empid,e.empname, e.salary;
creader c1%rowtype;  
cursor c2
is
  select empid, salary as new_sal
  from employee 
  where empid=p_id for update of salary;
rate_rec c2%rowtype;

v_new_salary number;
v_bonus number;
begin
  for creader in c1 loop
  for rate_rec in c2 loop
    if creader.avg_hours >= 10 then
        if creader.prj_count<4 then
           update employee set salary=salary*1.05
           where empid=rate_rec.empid
           return salary into v_new_salary;

    else
           update employee set salary=salary*1.1
           where empid=rate_rec.empid
          returning salary into v_new_salary;

       end if;
    end if;
  v_bonus:=v_new_salary-rate_rec.new_sal;

  dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID: '||creader.empid);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Name: '||creader.empname);
  dbms_output.put_line('Number of projects: '||creader.prj_count);
  dbms_output.put_line('Average Working Hours: '||creader.avg_hours);
  dbms_output.put_line('Old Salary: '||creader.old_sal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Bonus: '||v_bonus);
  dbms_output.put_line('New Salary: '||v_new_salary);

  end loop;
 end loop;



  end view_data;
  /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `rate_rec` is in scope in the loop, not outside. You should put all your `put_line` inside the loop.

`rate_rec.new_sal` is the old salary. The new one will be updated in the table, not in the record with the previous salary.

I propose that you do your updates and then you select once again and check that is has been modified. You could also use a `returning` clause in the updates to get the new salary.

Here is a possible solution. I have not checked thoroughly the query. There should probably be a `commit` at the end of the procedure.

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace procedure update_data(p_id number) is
prj_count integer;
avg_hours integer;
old_salary number;
new_salary number;
begin
    select count(a.projectid), round(avg(a.hours),0), e.salary
    into prj_count, avg_hours, old_salary
    from assignment a join employee e on a.empid=e.empid
    where e.empid=p_id
    group by e.salary;

    new_salary := old_salary;

    if avg_hours >= 10 then
        if prj_count<4 then
            update employee set salary=salary+salary*0.05
            where empid=p_id
            returning salary into new_salary;
        else
            update employee set salary=salary+salary*0.1
            where empid=p_id
            returning salary into new_salary;
        end if;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || old_salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || new_salary);
end update_data;
/
```

Comment: i am new at plsql, how can i do that without creating a new cursor

Comment: There were a few errors I have fixed. I also added code to display the old and new salary. Now it should do what you want